# pycrypto : No module named strxor

Tags: python, pycrypto

I got this error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
       from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
     File "C:\Users\Mokhles\Downloads\google-api-python-client-1.5.3\Crypto   \Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 57, in <module>
       import Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_PSS
     File "C:\Users\Mokhles\Downloads\google-api-python-client-1.5.3\Crypto   \Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py", line 74, in <module>
       from Crypto.Util.strxor import strxor
   ImportError: No module named strxor
```

any idea how to solve it?

ENV:
-windows 10
-python 2.7

Comment: Got error in what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're simply copied pyCrypto into your project. PyCrypto is library which depends on some native library/code (like libtomcrypt). You have to install it properly. You can do this for example through pip:

```
pip2 install pycrypto
```

or

```
pip3 install pycrypto
```

depending on which Python version you want to make it available.

Answer (score 0):

try `conda install pydotplus` (may need to install tqdm first)